# Appending DataFrames to an empty dataframe fails. Only shows the last DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the following and it is running successfully

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import date, datetime

currentDay = datetime.now().day
currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = datetime.now().year
date = f'{currentYear}-{currentMonth}-{currentDay}'

url = f'https://www.racingandsports.com.au/form-guide/GenerateRaceGuide?discipline=thoroughbred&country=south-korea&course=busan&date={date}&meetingId=291056&cols=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22HTab%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Tab%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22ND%22%2C%22size%22%3A%220.75%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FormFigs5%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Form%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22ND%22%2C%22size%22%3A%220.9375%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22HName%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Horse%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22S%22%2C%22size%22%3A%222.25%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22HBP%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22BP%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22ND%22%2C%22size%22%3A%220.75%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Jockey%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Jockey%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22S%22%2C%22size%22%3A%222.25%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Trainer%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Trainer%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22S%22%2C%22size%22%3A%222.25%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22HWeight%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Wt%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22D%22%2C%22size%22%3A%220.75%22%7D%5D&addCols=%5B%22prizemoney%22%5D&fs=S&page=port&preview=true'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)

appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,10):
  data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="parent"]/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/table').get_attribute('outerHTML')
  data_hdf = pd.read_html((data))[0]
  #listt = data_hdf.values.tolist()
  appended=appended_data.append(data_hdf)

appended
```

Now instead of getting all 9 tables I am only getting the last one even though it is appended as shown here:
[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
appended_data = []

for i in range(1,10):
    data= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="parent"]/div[{i}]/div[2]/div/table').get_attribute('outerHTML'),
    appended_data.append(pd.read_html((data))[0].to_dict('records'))

appended_data_pd = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
```

Appending single items to a dataframe is a bad and slow idea. Its not made for that.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are creating a new appended DataFrame each time in the for loop, this results in overwriting the previously created DataFrame which contains the last step data. If you want to concatenate each DataFrame created using red_html() inside the loop you should change your DataFrames' names like in the last line.

Also use concat() instead of append() since it is deprecated.  (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)

```
appended_data = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,10):
    data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="parent"]/div[{i}                       /div[2]/div/table').get_attribute('outerHTML')
    data_hdf = pd.read_html((data))[0]
 
    appended_data = pd.concat([appended_data, data_hdf])
```